# How to accept data in post request in both way through body and query string?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If we pass data in (post) request body than on server side we can find data in request.data and if someone pass data in query string we can get data in request.META['QUERY_STRING']. How to combine both and support both way to post data to server in api ?

Framework used:
 1. Django 
 2. Django RestFramework
 3. Django Filter

Comment: in django post data can be accessed using `request.POST` and get data i.e query string using `request.GET`. they both are a dict like objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can access data through `request.data` and query parameters through `request.query_params`.

```
class YourView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        posted_data_and_query = request.data.copy()
        posted_data_and_query.update(request.query_params)
```

But be aware of having elements with the same key in both `data` and `query_params`.

Comment: Now I am doubting, but does the `update` method return anything? It doesn't return for regular dictionaries. In any case, wouldn't it be safer to make `copy` first and then `update`? Something like: `pdaq = request.data.copy() ; pdaq.update(request.query_params)`

Comment: @MariusSiuram, `copy()` was returning a dictionary. But you're right, it would be better to copy first. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I didn't have any Django installation near to test the behaviour of the dictionary-like `data`, So I was doubting (I had make the mistake of using `update`, which returns `None` and breaking things a couple of times)